# Create PDF from Android App

Tags: android, pdf

I'm doing some research about what is the easiest way to create a PDF from ArrayList for example.

In this case, I'm trying to understand how to add my content to the InputStream required by class PdfDocumentAdapter (line 94). Because in this example the source is another pdf :)
[PdfDocumentAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Printing/PrintManager/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/print/PdfDocumentAdapter.java)

My question is, how to supply with info the input data in this case? (or let me know another easiest way to do without commercial libraries)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing some research about what is the easiest way to create a PDF from ArrayList for example

If your objective is an actual PDF, use a PDF-generating library (e.g., iText).

If your goal is to print, generate HTML and print from a `WebView`.

I do not recommend attempting to use the Android printing framework for generating general-purpose PDFs. You have little guarantee that those PDFs (today or tomorrow) will be usable outside of the Android printing framework.

> In this case, I'm trying to understand how to add my content to the InputStream required by class PdfDocumentAdapter (line 94). Because in this example the source is another pdf :)

That is because that sample is for printing an already-existing PDF. It has nothing to do with generating a PDF.

> or let me know another easiest way to do without commercial libraries

Generate the PDF on a server.

Answer (score 0):

What server aide script do u have. You can generate PDF on a server and download the file stream to your android app. 
Well it require internet connection.

Comment: I'm trying to do inside the app. Your suggestion is valid but with different approach. I have something with FPDF and PHP but I would like to solve just with the app. Thanks